# Python MySQL Error 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to write to a database as follows, but I get this error:

```
1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement
```

Execute statement:

```
query = "INSERT INTO db.tbl1(name, msg) VALUES (%s,%s)"
cursor.executemany(query, ([message.author.name], [message.content]))
mydb.commit()
```

Sorry im new to this. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it wrong
try this :

```
cursor.executemany(query, [(message.author.name, message.content)])
```